# Visual Studio Code HTML Preview issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm having an issue with VS Code, when I try to use JAVA Script in an HTML file. When I use the HTML preview it keeps saying that some content is disabled. But when I go to update the settings to allow the content, it never enables it. I've looked around the internet and couldn't find anything that would help me troubleshoot this issue. I'm just learning how to code, so I don't know that my code is good, but any help with the settings would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.[image]

Comment: Have you asked the author of whatever extension you are using?

Comment: I haven't asked that specific author, but I will. I have tried several different extensions

Comment: Yeah I would just to double tap. It might be worth annotating which extension you are using in your question the chance someone runs across this question that uses it. I personally don't use these kinds of extensions in favor of something like live server so I'm not much help. Here's [live server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) if you are intrested

Comment: I actually decided to move away from the HTML preview and you post for live server was perfect, thank you so much. It didn't really fix the issue with that extension, but I like this much better as it allows it to load into a web browser.